# Derived Tensor Product of Bimodules

Tags: tensor-products, sheaf-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

Let $A,B,C$ be sheaves of (possibly noncommutative) rings, $M$ a $(B,A)$-bimodule and $N$ a $(A,C)$-bimodule.

The object I am trying to understand is $M\otimes_{A}^{L}N$. I can choose a resolution $S^{\cdot}$ of $M$ conisting of flat right-$A$-modules and I can also choose a resolution $T^{\cdot}$ of $N$ consisting of flat left-$A$-modules and both $S^{\cdot}\otimes_{A}N$ and $M\otimes_{A}T^{\cdot}$ will be quasi isomorphic to $M\otimes_{A}^{L}N$ in the derived category of sheaves of abelian groups. While $S^{\cdot}\otimes_{A}N$ even  represents a complex of right $C$-modules and $M\otimes_{A}T^{\cdot}$ represents a complex of left $B$-modules, I was wondering if it was possible to consider $\_\otimes_{A}^{L}\_$ as a functor $D^{-}(Mod(B,A))\times D^{-}(Mod(A,C))\rightarrow D^{-}(Mod(A,C))$ and if this is possible, how to compute $M\otimes_{A}^{L}N$.

I guess it should be possible to find a resolution of $M$ consisting of modules which are flat both as left- $B$- and as right $A$- modules, but even if I do: The computation of $M\otimes_{A}^{L}N$, considered as an object in the derived category of abelian sheaves does not depend on the choice of acyclic resolution with right $A$-modules, but is it also independent from this choice in $D^{-}(Mod(B))$, the derived category of left-$B$-modules bounded below?

I'd be happy about both ideas and references.

Comment: I guess [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144020/pull-back-of-d-modules-and-koszul-resolution) relates to the question.

Comment: do you know for a fact that the category of modules over non-commutative ring objects in a sheaf topos have enough flats? assuming that, I don't see why this should be any different from how $-\otimes^L-$ extends to a functor in both variables in the commutative case

Comment: namely, you have to use a spectral sequence arguments as in Weibel's chapter on balancing the Tor functor. I think that should work for arbitrary abelian categories as long as you can resolve every object by a flat resolution.

Comment: I do not know the first statement for a fact, but I find the second reference helpful. Thanks for that!

Comment: Great! Note you can always assume that in the case of the categories you are working with, the 'enough flats' statement holds. It does hold in the category of $D$-modules over a scheme and it also holds in general for commutative ring objects, the point being that then you can define the derived tensor product

Comment: Once you get that, look up the sections on balancing the Tor functor in Weibel (as I mentioned before) and then look up the chapter in Weibel on derived categories. In that there is a section in which he explains why the usual tensor product can be extended as a bifunctor on $D^-(R-Mod)\times D^{-}(R-Mod)$. You probably just have to mimic the arguments there keeping track of non-commutativity. If there's more clarification needed, comment here and I will try to write up a full proof.

Comment: Note as an added reduction that a  $(B,A)$-module is the same as a left $B\otimes A^{op}$ module.

Comment: No need for further clarification. Thanks a lot!